# Theorem for convergence of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I was studying Infinite Series. The book I use is Thomas and Finney - Calculus and Analytical Geometry 9th Edition. On pg 635, the following theorem 6 was provided :

[image]

Theorem 6 says that when the sum , say

S = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + ..... + a(n)

is continued for infinite terms and converges resulting into a unique and finite value, then the limit of n tending to infinity of a(n) must be zero. This means that as we go further and further with our sum S, we reach to a term that would become, well, very close to zero.

I have tried thinking about it, but I could not really justify this theorem in any manner. The proof of the theorem is not given in the book. Could anyone please help ?

Comment: $a_n =s_n-s_{n-1} \to s-s=0$ where $s_n=a_1+a_2+..+a_n$ and $s$ is the sum of the series.

Comment: Say $a_n$ is bounded away from zero. Maybe $a_n > 1/100$ for every $n$. Do you see why the sum would be infinite? Is there anything special about $1/100$?

Comment: At least proofs of such simple theorems should be given in books. That Thomas Finney book is heavy with so many pages and yet does not provide simple proofs. Damn!

Comment: It is trivial IMO. If $a_n$ doesn't converge to zero, this means that exist an index $N$ such that for $n>N, |a_n|\ge d$ for a positive $d$. If you add infinite of these $d$ you get an infinite sum

Comment: Why downvote ? I am a beginner in this subject.

Comment: *What follows was intended to be a helpful comment for your just deleted question [Different results for ratio and root tests ?!](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3995752/13130). Since I spent several minutes formatting this before you deleted your question and I didn't want all that work to go to waste (and I can no longer post the comment there), I'm posting the comment to another one of your questions.* One of the properties of the limit operation is that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (AB) = (\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} A)(\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} B),$ **(continued)**

Comment: and by induction you can extend this so that for each positive integer $M$ we have $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (A_1 A_2 \cdots A_M) = (\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_1)(\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_2) \cdots (\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_M).$ However, when you were applying the root test, you used this rule for the case where the number of factors (i.e. $M)$ varies with $n,$ and when $M$ is allowed to vary with $n,$ this product rule for limits may no longer hold.

Comment: Thank you @DaveL.Renfro . I have figured out what the problem was when I applied the root test. There was someone who commented saying that I turned them all to 1 too quickly and I could understand how my evaluation was wrong. My view is this. It is actually possible to take out 3 common from each of the n terms of the numerator and 2 common from each of the n terms of the denominator. On applying the root test this makes the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a_n$ does $not$ converge to $0.$

Then we have some $r>0$ such that the set $S=\{n\in \Bbb N: |a_n|>r\}$ is infinite.

Now "$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges" means $b_n$ converges, where $b_n=\sum_{j=1}^na_j.$

But there are infinitely many $n>1$ for which $|b_n-b_{n-1}|>r,$ i.e. when $1<n\in S.$

So $b_n$ does not converge.